# Extend "system" logrotate rules without overwriting the package's definition

Tags: logrotate

The package manager installs a logrotate config file under `/etc/logrotate.d` for Apache2, which contains a `create 640 root adm` line. I want this to be a bit more liberate, e.g. `create 644 root adm`. I don’t like the idea of editing a file installed by the package manager; however, adding my own rule to `/etc/logrotate.conf` with the same log filename generates an error:

```
error: /etc/logrotate.conf:38 duplicate log entry for /var/log/apache2/access.log
```

Is there a way to extend such “system” rules, or do I just have to go on with editing the package manager’s files?

**PS:** my goal is to allow our developers to read the log files, especially error.log. If this is not possible, I will move onward to using file system ACLs, so I *do* know of other solutions. My question is specific to logrotate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is not; you will have to edit those files.  If you were using something like puppet for configuration management, you could express the change with Augeas, and there is likely some similar method available with Chef or cfengine, so at least you could be clear, in your configuration management source, what changes you have made from base/default configuration.

Comment: That’s what I was afraid of… thank you! This is a standalone server so we didn’t bother with puppet (or the like).

Comment: @GergelyPolonkai Puppet is quite well suited for managing your pets.